# PHP SOAPClient consuming MS Dynamics WSDL Methods behind Windows Authentication

Tags: php, wsdl, soap-client, dynamics-crm-365

I am trying to connect to a web service which requires a windows authentication. 
I am writing a code in PHP and trying to call methods of `MS dynamics 365 wsdl` 
but all I get is `Forbidden` and `608 error code: There is insufficient account information to log you on.`

I have tried the `NTLMSoapClient` and `NuSoap` classes, but when it doesn't throw a `Forbidden` message, it gives me NULL values of empty objects, which in the end still not getting the response from the method.

My code is similar to this

```
<?php 
$login = "user@dynamicsaccount.com";
$password = "password";
$url = "https://domainname.sandbox.ax.dynamics.com/pathto/soap/service/someservice?wsdl";
$arrayOpt = array(
"soap_version" => SOAP_1_1,
"cache_wsdl"   =>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
"exceptions"   =>false,
"trace"        =>true,
'authentication'=> SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC,
'login'        =>$login,
'password'     =>$password
);

$client = new SoapClient($url, $arrayOpt);
$param = array('someParam' => "value");

print_r($client->__getFunctions()); // i get the full functions from the wsdl
$result = $client->getInfo($param); 

var_dump($result); // i get a:Forbidden [Message]=>string(55) "There is insufficient account information to log you on"


?>
```

Even when I use `SOAPUI` I get the same result

```
  <s:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2009/WebFault">a:Forbidden</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Forbidden</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <Win32Exception xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ComponentModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
               <NativeErrorCode i:type="x:int" xmlns="">608</NativeErrorCode>
               <ClassName i:type="x:string" xmlns="">System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception</ClassName>
               <Message i:type="x:string" xmlns="">There is insufficient account information to log you on</Message>
               <Data i:nil="true" xmlns=""/>
               <InnerException i:nil="true" xmlns=""/>
               <HelpURL i:nil="true" xmlns=""/>
               <StackTraceString i:nil="true" xmlns=""/>
               <RemoteStackTraceString i:nil="true" xmlns=""/>
               <RemoteStackIndex i:type="x:int" xmlns="">0</RemoteStackIndex>
               <ExceptionMethod i:nil="true" xmlns=""/>
               <HResult i:type="x:int" xmlns="">-2147467259</HResult>
               <Source i:nil="true" xmlns=""/>
               <WatsonBuckets i:nil="true" xmlns=""/>
            </Win32Exception>
         </detail>
    </s:Fault>
```

I am expecting an array of strings as a response but I keep getting Forbidden and need more information. I don't know what information I need to pass to access the methods. What does Windows authentication need and how can I implement it using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this problem got Solved by using the Dynamics integration Samples for phpApplication from this github account [https://github.com/microsoft/Dynamics-AX-Integration](https://github.com/microsoft/Dynamics-AX-Integration/tree/master/ServiceSamples/PHPConsoleApplication)

And after reading Microsoft documents in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)  I understood it needed to get an authorization token from azure AD and that token needs to be added in my curl header as  Authorization: Bearer tokenString

instead of using SOAPClient I am using Curl to get into Dynamics AX
in doing so I got authorized and got in. I faced anotehr issue afterwards [you can find it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57311992/error-when-calling-dynamics-ax-soap-service-method-from-php/57344279#57344279) . And now I am facing a different issue; It seems I was able to get in with my Authorization Token Bearer Header, but I am getting:

```
Forbidden 1317 System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception The specified account does not exist
```

Which I created a different post for in case I solve it I will post my answer or if anyone already solved it .. please let me know.

[Here is the link to the my new Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57344486/forbidden-to-call-method-on-dynamics-ax-via-php-curl)